# Phonegap error when create new project

Tags: cordova

I'm getting this error when I tried to create a project with Phonegap

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Pedro-2:bin pedro$ ./create /Users/pedro/Dropbox/work/app/teste1 br.com.becodigital.teste1 teste1

./create: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

./create: line 1: '!DOCTYPE html>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should type this command like

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Pedro-2:bin pedro$ ./create /Users/pedro/Dropbox/work/app/teste1 org.apache.cordova.teste1 teste1
```

and the folder teste1 in your app folder should not exist

try this and send me back your result ;) hope this fix your issue